# how to display a fixed amount of template cards in a certain width of container of a website

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(119, 75, 75);
}

.navbar .left-nav #left {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
}

.navbar .left-nav #left a {
  padding: 3px 10px;
  font-size: 23px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  color: white;
}

.left-nav li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar .left-nav {
  /* border: 2px solid red; */
  width: 50%;
}

.navbar .right-nav {
  /* border: 2px solid blue; */
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
}

.navbar .right-nav input {
  padding: 5px 9px;
  margin: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.navbar .right-nav .btn {
  margin-right: 12px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 5px 14px;
}

.container {
  /* border: 2px solid red; */
  text-align: center;
}

.container h1 {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 5px 5px;
}

.container .first-box {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: bisque;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid violet;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.first-box .box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.first-box .box .addNote {
  margin: 5px 5px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.notes {
  background-color: rgb(221, 169, 101);
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.cards {
  display: flex;
}

.cards .card {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="left-nav">
    <ul id="left">
      <li><a href="#">Notes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="right-nav">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search notes">
    <button class="btn">search</button>
  </div>
</nav>
<section class="noteArea">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="first-box">
      <h1>Write your Note here</h1>
      <div class="box">
        <textarea name="note" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea>
        <button class="addNote">Add Note</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="notes">
  <hr>
  <h1>Your Notes</h1>
  <hr>
  <div class="card-box">
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="card">
        <h3> Note-1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi a veniam ratione ex aut, perferendis dignissimos alias ut illo debitis.</p>
        <button>Delete Note</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h3> Note-1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi a veniam ratione ex aut, perferendis dignissimos alias ut illo debitis.</p>
        <button>Delete Note</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h3> Note-1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi a veniam ratione ex aut, perferendis dignissimos alias ut illo debitis.</p>
        <button>Delete Note</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h3> Note-1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi a veniam ratione ex aut, perferendis dignissimos alias ut illo debitis.</p>
        <button>Delete Note</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h3> Note-1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi a veniam ratione ex aut, perferendis dignissimos alias ut illo debitis.</p>
        <button>Delete Note</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h3> Note-1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi a veniam ratione ex aut, perferendis dignissimos alias ut illo debitis.</p>
        <button>Delete Note</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h3> Note-1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi a veniam ratione ex aut, perferendis dignissimos alias ut illo debitis.</p>
        <button>Delete Note</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h3> Note-1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi a veniam ratione ex aut, perferendis dignissimos alias ut illo debitis.</p>
        <button>Delete Note</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h3> Note-1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi a veniam ratione ex aut, perferendis dignissimos alias ut illo debitis.</p>
        <button>Delete Note</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h3> Note-1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi a veniam ratione ex aut, perferendis dignissimos alias ut illo debitis.</p>
        <button>Delete Note</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h3> Note-1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi a veniam ratione ex aut, perferendis dignissimos alias ut illo debitis.</p>
        <button>Delete Note</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h3> Note-1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi a veniam ratione ex aut, perferendis dignissimos alias ut illo debitis.</p>
        <button>Delete Note</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

i want to make a note taking app and in this i want to display recorded notes in below container named as cards and i want to display cards in a row not more than 3-4 note card and want to display the next cards in the next row so how can i do that i have added some dummy cards in my html .
please suggest me the way to do so in a  beginner friendly way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `grid` instead of `flex` on `.cards` and remove the `width` of `.card`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(119, 75, 75);
}

.navbar .left-nav #left {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
}

.navbar .left-nav #left a {
  padding: 3px 10px;
  font-size: 23px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  color: white;
}

.left-nav li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar .left-nav {
  /* border: 2px solid red; */
  width: 50%;
}

.navbar .right-nav {
  /* border: 2px solid blue; */
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
}

.navbar .right-nav input {
  padding: 5px 9px;
  margin: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.navbar .right-nav .btn {
  margin-right: 12px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 5px 14px;
}

.container {
  /* border: 2px solid red; */
  text-align: center;
}

.container h1 {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 5px 5px;
}

.container .first-box {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: bisque;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid violet;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.first-box .box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.first-box .box .addNote {
  margin: 5px 5px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.notes {
  background-color: rgb(221, 169, 101);
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
}


/* This has been changed */

.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)
}

.cards .card {
  /* width: 300px; */
  margin: 2px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="left-nav">
    <ul id="left">
      <li><a href="#">Notes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="right-nav">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search notes">
    <button class="btn">search</button>
  </div>
</nav>
<section class="noteArea">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="first-box">
      <h1>Write your Note here</h1>
      <div class="box">
        <textarea name="note" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea>
        <button class="addNote">Add Note</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="notes">
  <hr>
  <h1>Your Notes</h1>
  <hr>
  <div class="card-box">
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="card">
        <h3> Note-1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi a veniam ratione ex aut, perferendis dignissimos alias ut illo debitis.</p>
        <button>Delete Note</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h3> Note-1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi a veniam ratione ex aut, perferendis dignissimos alias ut illo debitis.</p>
        <button>Delete Note</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h3> Note-1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi a veniam ratione ex aut, perferendis dignissimos alias ut illo debitis.</p>
        <button>Delete Note</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h3> Note-1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi a veniam ratione ex aut, perferendis dignissimos alias ut illo debitis.</p>
        <button>Delete Note</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h3> Note-1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi a veniam ratione ex aut, perferendis dignissimos alias ut illo debitis.</p>
        <button>Delete Note</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h3> Note-1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi a veniam ratione ex aut, perferendis dignissimos alias ut illo debitis.</p>
        <button>Delete Note</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h3> Note-1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi a veniam ratione ex aut, perferendis dignissimos alias ut illo debitis.</p>
        <button>Delete Note</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h3> Note-1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi a veniam ratione ex aut, perferendis dignissimos alias ut illo debitis.</p>
        <button>Delete Note</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h3> Note-1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi a veniam ratione ex aut, perferendis dignissimos alias ut illo debitis.</p>
        <button>Delete Note</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h3> Note-1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi a veniam ratione ex aut, perferendis dignissimos alias ut illo debitis.</p>
        <button>Delete Note</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h3> Note-1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi a veniam ratione ex aut, perferendis dignissimos alias ut illo debitis.</p>
        <button>Delete Note</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h3> Note-1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi a veniam ratione ex aut, perferendis dignissimos alias ut illo debitis.</p>
        <button>Delete Note</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```